# How to exit from Android App even if current Activity is not Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, exit

I have this activity flow

HomeActivity > Activity1 > Activity2 > Activity3 > HomeActivity

I switch back directly from Activity3 to HomeActivity  by pressing cancel button on Activity3.

but when I press back button on HomeActivity  I want to exit from the app, however it takes me back to Activity3... how to exit the app??? this is my code
on Home activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            finish();
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

if I press back button when App is just started on HomeActivity it works normally, closing the app...

How to make it work when I navigate through all these other activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch from Activity3 to HomeActivity this way:

```
Intent launchNextActivity = new Intent(Activity3.this, HomeActivity.class);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                  
launchNextActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(launchNextActivity);
```

Then `onBackPressed()` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all note that when navigating through the activities you create a stack of activities, this is why just calling `finish()` just finish your HomeActivity, then android gets the previous activity on the stack, which is Activity 3 and puts it on screen.

I would do this:

1) Call your HomeActivity, from Activity3 as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will call your HomeActivity and clear all your activities from the stack

2) On the HomeActivity `OnCreate()` add:

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit", false)){
    finish();
}
```

Hope this is helpful! and don't doubt on commenting if the code is not working or if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling 
finishAffinity(); in onBackPressed() of `HomeAactivity`.